# How to find the author of a NextCord button?

Tags: python, variables, button, discord.py

I have a button and I need to know the first 8 that click the button.

I would like:

- to store which users clicked the button in a variable
- **optionally** disable the button after 8 users have clicked it and/or after 30 secconds

Button code:

```
async def Play_button_callback():             
     stfu
    (I don't have anything here yet because I need the answer to this qestion)
```

Comment: If you don't want strangers to push your buttons, just shoo them away from them. Seriously, though, you will need to show the code you have so far; probably you have a click handler of some sort where you already can print out the clicker, and maybe some storage too...

Comment: first, of all, I am not worried about the stranger part.  and for the code, here it is.
```Play_button = button(label='', style=ButtonStyle.blurple)``` I am making a ticket system and the first 8 people  to push the ```Play_button``` in 30 seconds are in.
```async def Play_button_callback():
            stfu```(I don't have anything here yet because I need the answer to this qestion)

Comment: Is that _all_ of the code you have? You should edit the actual code you have into your post, not put a bit of it in the comments here.

Comment: Sorry just re-edited the measge

Comment: (1) Edit the code _into your post, not into the comments_. (2) How are you wiring that `Play_button_callback` up to the button?

Comment: ```Play_button.callback = Play_button_callback```

Comment: Thats how i will ""wiring that Play_button_callback up to the button?"

Comment: I will do the other stuff after I have this info because I need this first